# Limit pagination in wordpress to a post published in certain period

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a latest version of wp.

I need this kind of functionality but not sure how to do it.

I want to post an blog article which will be available on its main category listing page for set period (from published from & to date - to date is the last date until when it will accessible on category page using pagination. But after to date this will not be list in category using pagination. But still stays on given url and accessible by direct url for SEO reason.

Basically I want to make a pagination to be valid for only a post published under certain period.

Both cases are fine, do you know any plugin which can be used or need to customize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about a plugin, but you can simply customize your wp_query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters, and make sure you use the "paged" parameter described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters